# c#: Accessing object properties in Extension Methods

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I'm currently writing a c# Rummikub game.

I have an object named **Card** that has *Value* and *Color* properties.
Also, inside **Player**'s Class, I have a *list of cards* (player's hand).

In the Player class, I wrote some methods that get only the player's hand as parameter. stuff like:

> ```
>     // Determines what card should the CPU throw.
>     public int CardToThrow(List<Card> CPUHand).
>
>     // Call:
>     int cardToThrow = Player1.CardToThrow(Player1.Hand);
> ```

I want to be able to call the function like this:

> ```
>     int cardToThrow = Player1.Hand.CardToThrow();
> ```

When I tried to write the Extension Method, I didn't manage to acces the card's properties:

> ```
> public static class HandExtensionMethods
> {
>     public static int foo<Card>(this List<Card> list)
>     {
>         return list[0].Value;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Error:

> 'Card' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension
>   method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'Card' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How should I write the extension methods so I could access the object properties?

Comment: Card class does not have definition of Value

Comment: Can you show your Card class? It obviously doesn't have a public member called "Value".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your extension method is generic with a parameter type of `Card` which is shadowing the concrete `Card` class. Remove the generic parameter:

```
public static int foo(this List<Card> list)
{
    return list[0].Value;
}
```